# Looping through multi tables in jQuery and adding data-labels to each td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that takes the th values and adds them to data-label's for each td. I then convert them in CSS to show a mobile view of the table. It all works fine but when you have multiple tables with different headers it takes the last table on the page and adds these data-label's to all the tables.

I cant seem to see what I am doing wrong and wondered if anyone could help?

```
$('table').each(function() { 
  if ($(this).find('th').length > 1) { 
    thcount = 0
    $(this).find('th').each(function() {
      eachth = $(this)  
      thcount=thcount+1     
      $('tr td:nth-child('+thcount+')').each(function(a) {
        if (eachth.html() == '') {
          $(this).css('padding-left', '6px');
        } else {
          $(this).attr('data-label', eachth.html() + '\u00A0'); 
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. What should happen and what is happening now? Could you elaborate a bit? And maybe add a part of your html where the mistake is happening :)

Comment: What it does it that it takes the headings for each table column and adds this to each td's data-label for the corresponding column it works correctly but if their are multiple tables it takes the data from the last table and adds this to all the tables on the page

Comment: <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-label="ID">149</td>
            </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>

Comment: _"it takes the last table on the page and adds these data-label's to all the tables"_ - no, that is not actually what happens. It goes through each of your tables, and processes the TH of each individual one. But it _writes_ the data to the cells of _all_ tables, because you did not limit the selection of those: `$('tr td:nth-child('+thcount+')')` selects among _all_ TDs on the whole page. Your forgot to limit  _this_ selection to only the current table as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to do it in one `th` each. For example, like this:

```js
$('table').each(function(){
  const table = $(this);
  table.find('th').each(function(index) {
    table.find(`td:nth-child(${index + 1})`).attr( 'data-label', $(this).text() + ' ' );
  })
})
```

```css
table th,
table td {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```